# “await this.method();” doesn’t work in static method

Tags: javascript, static, async-await, es6-promise, es6-class

I know of the ES6 `await` feature and I’d like to use it in a function I created in a class.

It works well, but when the function is a `static` function, it doesn’t. Is there any reason for that? Also, what will be the right way to be able to use `await` inside a `static` function?

```
class MyClass {
  resolveAfter2Seconds() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('resolved');
      }, 2000);
    });
  }

  static async asyncCall() {
    console.log('calling');
    var result = await this.resolveAfter2Seconds();
    console.log(result);
    // expected output: "resolved"
  }
}

MyClass.asyncCall();
```

Comment: It should work. In what way does it not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `await` just fine in a static function.  That is not your issue.

BUT, `this` in a static function is `MyClass` so `this.someMethod()` is looking for another static method, not an instance method and  `resolveAfter2Seconds()` is an instance method, not a static method so `this.resolveAfter2Seconds()` won't find that method because that's like calling `MyClass.resolveAfter2Seconds()` which doesn't exist.

If you also make `resolveAfter2Seconds()` be `static`, then it would probably work because `this` inside `asyncCall()` is `MyClass` so `this.resolveAfter2Seconds()` is looking for another static method.

This should work where you make `resolveAfter2Seconds` also be static:

```
class MyClass {

  static resolveAfter2Seconds() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('resolved');
      }, 2000);
    });
  }

  static async asyncCall() {
    console.log('calling');
    var result = await this.resolveAfter2Seconds();
    console.log(result);
    // expected output: "resolved"
  }
}
```

Or, you could reach into the prototype and call it from there because it is actually a static method (doesn't reference `this` at all):

```
  static async asyncCall() {
    console.log('calling');
    var result = await MyClass.prototype.resolveAfter2Seconds();
    console.log(result);
    // expected output: "resolved"
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `await this.resolveAfter2Seconds();` as if the `this` was an instantiation of `MyClass`, but in the context that your'e calling it, it isn't - `resolveAfter2Seconds` is a method on the *prototype* of `MyClass`, it's not a property of the class itself. Call the prototype method instead:

```js
class MyClass {
  resolveAfter2Seconds() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('resolved');
      }, 2000);
    });
  }
  static async asyncCall() {
    console.log('calling');
    var result = await this.prototype.resolveAfter2Seconds();
    console.log(result);
    // expected output: "resolved"
  }

}
MyClass.asyncCall();
```